# Is there a rule of thumb for choosing polygon width?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, ground, eaglecad, routing

I am currently using the same width as the smallest wire inside the polygon, is this too small?

Comment: I little more detail would help you get an answer to your question.  A couple of images would help make it more clear exactly what your asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eagle, the "width" parameter associated with a polygon is the width of the stroke used to fill it. A wider stroke will be less able to fill narrow gaps between other conductors. But a stroke that is too narrow will cause the resulting Gerber file to be huge because of the number of strokes required.

The width of the narrowest wire used elsewhere in your design is a good starting point, unless you have huge areas of polygon that need to be filled.